# Pass in object and array variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have dialog in a javascript object separated into objects and arrays (similar to JSON format).

I'd like to access these objects and arrays by passing in their respective variable names...

For example, how would I access the "parent_object_name" object and child array "array_name"? I've tried creating objects and arrays, then passing them in, as such:

```
var parent_object_name = npc_dialog.people[NPC_id].dialogs.answers;
var child_array_name = npc_dialog.people[NPC_id].dialogs.answers.AnswerOne;
cycleDialog(0, parent_object_name, child_array_name);
```

But that didn't work...

So then I tried passing the names in as strings:

```
cycleDialog(0, "parent_object_name", "child_array_name");
```

This also didn't work.

cycleDialog takes those variables and substitutes them in as such:

```
function cycleDialog(NPC_id, TYPE, SUBTYPE) {
    NPCs_ARRAY[NPC_id].children[1].text = npc_dialog.people[NPC_id].dialogs.TYPE.SUBTYPE[dialog_id];
}
```

Thank you

---

EDIT:

Data looks like:

```
"dialog" : 
{   
    "dialog_name" :
    [ 
              "dialog",
              "more text..."
    ]
},
"answers" : 
{   
    "answer_name" :
    [ 
              "answer text here",
              "more text..."
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is this any different than your other question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
function cycleDialog(NPC_id, TYPE, SUBTYPE) {
    NPCs_ARRAY[NPC_id].children[1].text = npc_dialog.people[NPC_id].dialogs[TYPE][SUBTYPE][dialog_id];
}
```

along with:

```
cycleDialog(0, parent_object_name, child_array_name);
```

The difference between `.x` and `[x]` is that `.x` looks up the key `'x'`, whereas `[x]` looks up the key that the variable `x` evaluates to:

```
> var array = {x: 100, foobar: 200}
> var x = 'foobar';
> array.x
100
> array[x]
200
```

Comment: So now when I pass in `cycleDialog(0, "answers", "Mandarin");`, `dialogs` should be able to look up the keys that match the strings "answers" and "Mandarin", right? It says `Cannot read property 'answers' of undefined` though

Comment: @Growler: That means that `npc_dialog.people[NPC_id].dialogs` is `undefined` instead of what you expect.

Comment: Okay, thank you. That difference (`.x` and `[x]`) you mentioned above, in terms of accessing the key value vs accessing the key that the variable evaluates to... is that just used for objects, or can you have a similar structure with arrays to?

Comment: @Growler: that's the same for arrays also, although `x.1` is invalid syntax so you can't do it that way for numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass variables to a function by passing their names.
The only way to do that would be to pass their address or value.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `cycleDialog` gets the data from the object `npc_dialog.people[NPC_id].dialogs`. If I understand correctly, all you need to do is pass it the names of the objects within that object that you want it to look up, and follow Claudiu's answer for altering the `cycleDialog`
function.

e.g. `cycleDialog(0, 'answers', 'answer_name');`

would return `[ 
              "answer text here",
              "more text..."
    ]`

using the example data you give (and assuming this data is found within `npc_dialog.people[0].dialogs`).